# working with crystal report 10 and vb6.0

Tags: vb6, crystal-reports

I have created a sample report with crystal report 10. 
Now, I wanna to add it to my vb6.0 project but when I try to do so by add file from project menu, it says that sampleReport.rpt could not b loaded....

what's wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What version of Crystal Reports 10? I think you need one of the Developer Editions for VB6 integration.

Alternatively, the default install of VB6 has the components for Crystal 4.5 included. Open Project > Components, then select the Designers tab. Deselect any version of Crystal apart from the entry for Crystal 10 Designer (which should be there if you have the Crystal Developer Edition). This should add an option to the Project menu for adding a Crystal 10 report to your project.

Comment: well, I read the release note of it. It seems that it's standard edition of Crystal Reports 10.
As you said, I sould be able to add a Crystal report to my vb project
but there's no option in porject menu !

Comment: I'm afraid that if you only have the standard edition you will not be able to use a Crystal 10 report with Visual Basic. Only the Developer editions give you the components to do this (as well as the licence to do so). This is why the option is not available.
As you can see from here :

http://www.recrystallize.com/merchant/crystal-reports/crystal-reports-10-editions.htm

the Standard edition has no components at all for application integration.

Answer (score 0):

I use to use Crystal Reports and VB6. 
the way we use to do it was to ship the reports in a reports folder, and reference them at runtime via the Crystal reports viewer. Would this solution work for you?

Comment: Well, no because I wanna to design C.R. within the Vb6.0 enviroment not creating them in C.R. IDE and then link them to my project.